# swt rcp message dialog without any button and no modal

Tags: dialog, swt, message, rcp

I need your help, In my swt app I need to show a simple message while some jfreechart chart is loading. Simply I put a shell at the beginning of the chart generating method and I close that shell at the end of the method. I know is not the best solution but I need a simply way to do that. The problem is that the shell is modal and it closes some other jobs running before, so I need a NO MODAL pop up. I tried with message box and dialogs but all of them have buttons, I only need a pop up without any buttons, with a only a label and an image.
Thanks!

I put the relevant code:

in the generating chart method I call the shell create method:

```java
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display,SWT.BACKGROUND);
    generateMessageDialog(display,shell);
```

and this is the method to create the shell:

```java
    Monitor primary = display.getPrimaryMonitor ();
    Rectangle bounds = primary.getBounds ();
    shell.setSize(455, 295);
    Rectangle rect = shell.getBounds ();
    int x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - rect.width) / 2;
    int y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - rect.height) / 2;
    shell.setLocation (x, y);
    shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());
    shell.setText("Information");
    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    ImageDescriptor id =      Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/loading4_modificado.gif");
    Image image = id.createImage();
    label.setImage(image);

    Label label2=new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label2.setText("Generating chart. Please, wait...");

    FormData label1FD = new FormData();
    label1FD.top = new FormAttachment(0, 120);
    label1FD.left = new FormAttachment(0, 90);
    label.setLayoutData(label1FD);

    FormData label2FD = new FormData();
    label2FD.top = new FormAttachment(0, 130);
    label2FD.left = new FormAttachment(0, 160);
    label2.setLayoutData(label2FD);
    label2.setFont(new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font(null,"Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10));

    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
```

Comment: I tried that Greg but it´s still not working well...Thanks anyway!

Comment: Note you have `SWT.BACKGROUND` being passed in as the style to the `Shell`. AFAIK Shell does not support that style bit: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html

Comment: Thanks all! I resolved the problem with a trick with other composite, making it visible or not, instead a pop up message. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the Shell with a style something like this:

```java
new Shell(parentShell, SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.TOOL | SWT.NO_FOCUS);
```

gives you a 'tool tip' style shell.

Comment: If you like to prevent the user from interacting with other parts of the application while this Shell is open you can add the `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` style flag.

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? What are you getting and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are asking for something a little like a splash screen.

The key style you probably want is [`SWT.ON_TOP`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/SWT.html#ON_TOP) which puts the window on top.

There is a full splash screen example as part of [SWT Snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) here: [Snippet104](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet104.java)